# Change color of hyperlink in alternate rows of table CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I have changed the color of alternate rows of table using following CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#dedede; color: black; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:none; }
```

But I want to change the color of hyperlinks in alternate rows using CSS.
I tried to change the color using

```
tr:nth-child(odd) a{ background-color:#dedede; color: black; }
tr:nth-child(even) a{ background-color:none; }
```

But it doesn't works for me

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's working fine dear try this :

```
tr:nth-child(odd) a{ background-color:#dedede; color: #996633; }
tr:nth-child(even) a{ background-color:none; color : #FF0000}
```